# Error en android API 22 y 21 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android-studio, android

Tengo un problema con android studio, al correr mi app en dispositivos con API 21 y 22, muestro mi Log:

```
03-16 10:52:33.930 3387-3387/com.lms_la.njoyapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.lms_la.njoyapp, PID: 3387
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lms_la.njoyapp/com.lms_la.njoyapp.LoadingActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lms_la.njoyapp.LoadingActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:915)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:710)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lms_la.njoyapp.LoadingActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:915) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:710) 
  Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lms_la.njoyapp.LoadingActivity
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
          ... 14 more
  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lms_la.njoyapp.LoadingActivity
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
          ... 13 more
  Cause
```

Y mi manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.lms_la.njoyapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        tools:node="replace" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        tools:node="replace" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <application
        android:name=".BeaconConnection"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/frontloader92"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

en gradle lo tengo así:

```
applicationId "com.lms_la.njoyapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
```

Alguna idea de por qué ocurre esto solo en dispositivos con sistemas menores a Marshmallow?
De antemano muchas gracias!

Actualización:
Clase LoadingActivity:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocationManager mlocManager;
    private boolean enabled;
    private ImageView dialog_loading;
    private GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget;
    private Thread timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        Log.e("netHabilitada", Boolean.toString(isNetDisponible()));
        Log.e("accInternet",   Boolean.toString(isOnlineNet()));

        mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (enabled == true) {
            switch (Boolean.toString(isNetDisponible())) {
                case "true":
                    switch (Boolean.toString(isOnlineNet())) {
                        case "true":
                            Inicio();
                            break;
                        case "false":
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                    .setTitle("Conexión a internet requerida")
                                    .setMessage("Para poder usar esta app es necesario que actives Tu conexión a internet y tengas datos disponibles")
                                    .setPositiveButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //un listener que al pulsar, cierre la aplicacion
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            //Salir
                                            finishAffinity();
                                        }
                                    }).show();
                            break;
                    }

                    break;
                case "false":
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setTitle("Conexión a internet requerida")
                            .setMessage("Para poder usar esta app es necesario que actives Tu conexión a internet")
                            .setPositiveButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //un listener que al pulsar, cierre la aplicacion
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //Salir
                                    finishAffinity();
                                }
                            }).show();
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation)
                    .setTitle("Localización GPS requerida")
                    .setMessage("Para poder usar esta app es necesario que actives la localización GPS (Ir a: Configuración > Ubicación > Activado -> Modo: Alta precisión).")
                    .setPositiveButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {//un listener que al pulsar, cierre la aplicacion
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //Salir
                            finishAffinity();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetDisponible() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo actNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return (actNetInfo != null && actNetInfo.isConnected());
    }

    public Boolean isOnlineNet() {
        try {
            Process p = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.n-joy.com.mx");
            int val = p.waitFor();
            boolean reachable = (val == 0);

            return reachable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Inicio() {
        dialog_loading = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_loading);
        imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(dialog_loading);
        Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.frontloader)
                .into(imageViewTarget);

        timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(8000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent actividaPrincipal = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
                    startActivity(actividaPrincipal);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: agrega la actividad en tu manifest

Comment: está en el manifest:
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        y solo ocurre con lollipop

Comment: Al parecer no encuentra la clase en la ruta en la que debería estar: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lms_la.njoyapp.LoadingActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.lms_la.njoyapp-2/base.apk", zip file...`

Comment: pero si pruebo la app en un dispositivo con sistema operativo 6.0 en adelante funciona correctamente, eso solo me ocurre con dispositivos 5.1 y 5.0

Comment: Es posible que a causa de buscar tu clase por reflection el `_` en tu nombre de tu paquete te causa problemas. Prueba si te funciona si lo refacturas a `com.lmsla.njoyapp` y `com.lmsla.njoyapp2`. Es generalmente recomendado de usar [a-z][a-z0-9]* para nombres de paquetes.

Comment: ya cambié todo, ahora el package no tiene guión bajo, y sigue igual solo con lollipop

Comment: @SergioGarcía  que implementa tu clase LoadingActivity? si es una clase podrías agregarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrañamente quedo solucionado de la siguiente manera:
Agregué en build.gradle:

```
dependencies{compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0' compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'}
```

y listo, ya funciona correctamente desde android 5.0 hasta 7.1.1
Agradezco su apoyo a todos!

Comment: ¿Que es diferente a lo que tenias, o agregaste todas las dependencias que mencionas?

Comment: actualice estas dependencias